# how to access http://host.docker.internal:80 in docker-compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my docke-compose.yml look like this

```
services:
  goporxy:
    image: goproxy/goproxy
    container_name: goporxy
    hostname: goporxy
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./goporxy:/go
    ports:
      - "80:8081" 

  goserver:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: goserver
    hostname: goserver
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - goporxy
```

if build it, get error

`go: github.com/Joker/hpp@v1.0.0: Get "http://host.docker.internal:80/github.com/%21joker/hpp/@v/v1.0.0.mod": dial tcp 192.168.65.2:80: connect: connection refused`

but if i run `docker run -d -p80:8081 goproxy/goproxy` befor `docker-compose up` and remove goporxy in docker-compose.yml

the goporxy correct function and start downloading dependencies

(in goserver Dockerfile i has setting goproxy like `RUN go env -w GOPROXY=http://host.docker.internal:80,direct` )

I want use docker-compse do two things at once , how to do?

Comment: This has always been one of my pet-peeves with docker compose. The depends on "just" waits for the docker instance to be instantiated, not when it's ready. The only solution I found (which is dirty) is to make it so the server keeps trying to connect to the machine until eventually it does. I included a wait statement in my python client for this. Don't know if that is an option for you?

Comment: Even `depends_on:` isn't having an effect here: there's no way for one container's _build_ to depend on another container being running.  You need to launch the proxy separately, possibly outside of Docker.

Comment: @Ludo21South I want to avoid this

Comment: @DavidMaze yep , my test also shows that this works, but not the workaround I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose syas :
depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

this is the detail:[https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/]

actually,you can run a shell before the container start command execution.The shell will ping api or visit your web to judge the container if ready then start the real service.There is a ready-made solution. The SH script is called "wait for". Just download the shell and add it in the dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
```

then add this in docker-compose.yml

```
command: sh -c './wait-for.sh "the server depended:port" -- "the code run the server"'
```

Comment: so, if want to accomplish all of this in docker-compose, at this now, only can use link "wait for" in container run ?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/      It's on official documents,I used this before